# Twitter Oauth Error - Could Not Authenticate You - Error Code:32

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am trying to get user detail using twitter api - oauth,

User authorization stage was over in my application.

At final stage i am not able to get the twitter user detail. Please tell me what i have done wrong.

The url i am getting at final stage after user authorization is as below,

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=BDLNYIIJedJpJz5I7wwSA&oauth_nonce=6e1e29b2a8d38e4a50179d5568b7d89a&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1395669350&oauth_token=147476905-H5MQGFOgXk0xKZQ1P6x7cNAB6ye7VihVFxA7mb2I&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=FfydkjTfBVUcmHlc50wg6bJ6G0s%3D](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=BDLNYIIJedJpJz5I7wwSA&oauth_nonce=6e1e29b2a8d38e4a50179d5568b7d89a&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1395669350&oauth_token=147476905-H5MQGFOgXk0xKZQ1P6x7cNAB6ye7VihVFxA7mb2I&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=FfydkjTfBVUcmHlc50wg6bJ6G0s=)

I searched a lot of forum including stackoverflow for more than 3 hours. I am not able to get the solution for this. Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you double check your keys?

Comment: Have you gone through this link https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11494

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL i checked the keys. all are correct :(

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I have also seen that link. But no solution for me. :(

Comment: I suggest you to regenerate your keys on twitter app page.

Comment: regenerated and tested now. same error it comes.. :(

Comment: No one is there to solve this?

Comment: Show us how exactly you are building that URL.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when I use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/.

Here is my solution:

On app page => settings => Check "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" and Callback URL ( this is URL of your site when you input token keys).

When you refresh you site you will see the sign in and click that will direct you to authorization and after that it works.